# Using overflow:hidden in an iPhone web app?

Tags: css, iphone

I'm currently working on a website for the iPhone. The website is longer than the viewport of the iPhone, so I want to hide the overflow. How can I do this?

I'm already using…

```
<meta name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
```

... so it's not possible to scale the viewport. I don't want to be able to scroll it vertically if the page is bigger than the viewport.

Setting the height of the body to 480px doesn't seem to change this behavior:

```
body, html {
    height: 480px;
}
```

How can I implement this?

Comment: Hey matt, did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

What about this?:

```
body
{
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: You may have to set the width __and__ height explicitly, that `overflow: hidden` works.